# CSS fixed background has white line on the left

Tags: css, background, webkit

I tried to put a background on my whole page with

```
html {
    background: url(images/panda.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This generally works just fine, but I have discovered a problem: On the left-hand side of the screen is a white stripe. Is it possible to fix that?

PS: Just in advance: No, that stripe is not on the picture. You can get an impression of how it looks:

[image]

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/uhwcW/
When zooming in/out the white stripe sometimes disappears or switches sides... Confusing.

Comment: Try changing the second center to left. `no-repeat center left fixed;`

Comment: just check your image it has white line in the image itself at left side.. check it in firefox

Comment: Kyle: When changing it like described, the white stripe is on the right? Maybe the image is just too small? But its resolution is 1920x1080?

Uttara: There is no white linke on the left...

Comment: can you make a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yep. Did that. See my edit of the inital post.

Comment: You might want to try this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626206/rogue-white-line-appearing-on-background-image][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626206/rogue-white-line-appearing-on-background-image

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0
```

in your CSS for `html`.

Comment: I already tried that, but deleted margin and padding after I did not see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset your body? Try this for other containers too, maybe it's just some margin or padding you're seeing...

```
body { 
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @Kuf, ah I already wondered why the highlighting went wrong, thnx ;-)

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this as well... The only container here is the body and the CSS therefor looks just like your suggestion.

Comment: If I set the `background-position: 1px;` to `background-position: 0px;` the problem appears to be gone correct? http://jsfiddle.net/uhwcW/5/

Comment: This is normally not part of my CSS file - I accidentally put it in the jsfiddle version because i was trying that as well before...

You are right, when changing it to background-position: 0px; the image is fixed to the left - but I think the white stripe is on the right then?

Comment: Maybe this is a scaling problem due to widescreen displays or specific screen resolutions?
I changed my default setting (1366 x 768) to any other resolution and did not experience this problem...

Comment: Ah shoot! I thought I solved it... Maybe you should make sure it's your background you are seeing. Try changing the body-color to red or something. Or do you already know for sure?

Comment: When changing the body color, the stripe changes color as well, so I think it's a scaling problem... Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to reproduce you problem. I took the code of jsfiddle.net and removed the `background-position` attribute. Whatever screen I work on it seems to work fine. I don't have a monitor that supports 1366 x 768 so I guess I can't help you...

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

```
html{
    background: url(..//index3.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a center after the url did it for me

like this:

```
background: url(images/panda.jpg) center;
```