# Rogue white line appearing on background image

Tags: html, css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:url('http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Hello brethren. I've been trying to get this scalable background image to work on this website, but the facking thing has a weird rogue white line on the left hand side.

http://jsfiddle.net/49n73/1/

Use the fiddle to get an idea of the problem, make sure you pull the 'results' window as large as it can go so you can actually see the rogue line. What is causing this?

Comment: What browser / OS are you using?  I couldn't see any problems (Firefox / Linux)...

Comment: Hmm.  I've only got access to this one set-up, but it'd be a good idea to try it in a couple browsers to see if it's a common problem, or just a rendering bug in Chrome.

Comment: try this updated fiddle, I've added my sidebars in this, it helps to accentuate the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/49n73/5/

EDIT: This doesn't happen on Firefox... wierd.. only chrome... WAT DO?!?!

Comment: I don't see it on Firefox 18.0.1 and Win7. Scaled it over three screens, there's no white line: http://i.imgur.com/x9eLWKO.jpg

Comment: No it doesn't occur on firefox, only Chrome so far

Comment: 1) Did you know you can share a full screen result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/49n73/5/embedded/result/. 2) It seems to be a scaling bug, as the line doesn't appear at ALL large sizes you have to move it around to find it.

Comment: yeah I know, but the line doesn't appear in the JSfiddle screenshot. The fiddle is the only place displaying the white line that I can see :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to be a scaling bug combined with the `background-image` being centre aligned.

It can be fixed by changing:

```
background:url('http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed;
```

to this:

```
background:url('http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg')no-repeat 0 0 fixed;
```

So what this does is change the `background-position` from `center center` to `0 0`. So it will always be scaled from the top left and never leave a gap (the white line) at the side.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/49n73/11/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves the problem. How did you figure this out, just out of interest? I'm new to coding and I didn't even know where to begin problem solving.

Comment: I've got white line either on the left or on the right only when browser window is maximized! Chrome only.

Comment: I just added 'background-color' property so it's almost invisible.

Comment: You should add the properties separate, so it's easier to understand for newbies.

Comment: @julmot: The css was written in the same form as it was in the question so as to avoid confusion for the person I was helping i.e. the question asker. I don't believe it would have been helpful to rewrite their css in long hand. However, I do explain after the code example exactly what css property has been changed i.e. `background-position`. I don't see how that warrants a down vote.